# reCAPTCHA Invisible - reSubmit Form Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

While using reCaptcha, I faced a problem. In code, using AJAX to submit form. Before submitting I need to check if the fields are filled or not. If fields are not filled, submit should not happen.

In this case, if textfields are not filled, it will give an alert.

The problem is after the rejection of invalid post, the submit button stops working for like 2 or 3 minutes and there is no error given by reCaptcha. After the period of time, reCaptcha starts working again and submit button works.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="javascript:void(0)">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="name">
       <input type="text" placeholder="E-Mail" id="email">
       <textarea placeholder="Message" id="message">/textarea>
       <button class="g-recaptcha pull-right" data-sitekey="#your-site-key" data-callback="sendData" type="submit"> SEND <i class="flaticon-origami34"></i> </button>
</form>
```

Javascripts :

```
function sendData(){

    console.log('send data - '); // --> works

    //send datas: 

    $("#contact-form").submit();

};

$('#contact-form').on("submit", function() {

console.log('clicked submit'); // --> works

name = $('#name').val().replace(/<|>/g, ""), // prevent xss
    email = $('#email').val().replace(/<|>/g, ""),
    msg = $('#message').val().replace(/<|>/g, "");

if (name == '' || email == '' || msg == '') {

    alert("Please fill all areas !");

} else {

    console.log('captcha response: ' + grecaptcha.getResponse()); // --> captcha response: 

    // ajax to the php file to send the mail
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SaveContact.php",
        data: "email=" + email + "&name=" + name + "&msg=" + msg + "&g-recaptcha-response=" + grecaptcha.getResponse()
    }).done(function(status) {
        if (status == "ok") {
            // clear the form fields
            $('#name').val('');
            $('#email').val('');
            $('#message').val('');
        }
    });

}});
```

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: not working, for 2 or 3 minutes. After that working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible), you can also call `grecaptcha.reset(opt_widget_id);`, where `opt_widget_id` is optional and will default to the first recaptcha widget created.

Answer (score 2):

Then you need to reset cooldown of invisible recaptcha, you could use a hack like this

```
var recaptchaIframe = document.querySelector('.grecaptcha-badge iframe');
recaptchaIframe.src = recaptchaIframe.src;
```

I don't have a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out and wanted to post it in case anyone else has the same issue.  Google's example code set's the button id as "submit" and calling the "submit" function from within onSubmit was failing because of it.  Changing the id to anything else fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

if you render recaptcha explicitly in a script like this:

```
var form = grecaptcha.render('idSelector', {
  'sitekey' : 'your_sitekey',
  'callback': callableFunction

}, true)
```

then, "form" variable contains widget_id, so you can reset that recaptcha like this

```
grecaptcha.reset(form);
```